# Bubble sort worst case, best case and average case complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, bubble-sort

What is the (a) worst case, (b) best case, and (c) average case complexity of the following function which does bubble sorting

```
for i=1 to n-1 do
    for j=i to n-1 do
        if x[j]>x[j+1] then
            temp=x[j]
            x[j]=x[j+1]
            x[j+1]=temp
        end {if}
    end {for}
end {for}
```

How would you justify the complexity?

Comment: What have you come up with so far ?

Comment: Pretty much sounds like you want us to formulate an answer for your homework

Comment: Bubble sort complexity discussions are very common on the 'net, and I don't see that anyone would have questions about it unless it was homework. Tried googling "bubble sort complexity"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worst case is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The average case is also O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The worst case too is O(n<sup>2</sup>), even though the code inside the if statement will not get executed in this case. The quadratic complexity is due to the fact that the two for loops will execute completely in all the three cases irrespective of the content of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thats true with below BubbleSort algorithm as well, since while is O(n) as well.

```
public static void BubbleSort( int [ ] num )
    {
        int j;
        boolean flag = true;  
        int temp;  

        while ( flag )
        {

            flag= false;   
            for( j=0;  j < num.length -1;  j++ )
            {
                if ( num[ j ] > num[j+1] )   
                {
                    temp = num[ j ];                //swap elements
                    num[ j ] = num[ j+1 ];
                    num[ j+1 ] = temp;
                    flag = true;              //shows a swap occurred
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bubble sort algorithm which changes dramatically for best, worst and average case efficiency, try this:

```
int count = n - 1;    // The input size
bool sFlag = true;    // A flag variable allowing the inner outerloop to 
                         break early and fall through

while (sFlag ){

    sFlag = false;    // Set false so that the loop can break if no swaps occur
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
        if (A[j+1] < A[j]){

            int temp;    // Swap the two elements
            temp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[j+1];
            A[j+1] = temp;

            sFlag = true;    // A swap has occured, iterate again
        }
    }
    count--;    //Next time, don't bother looking at the last element, it is 
                  in order

}
```

The Worst case for this is Cworst(n) = 1/2n(n+1), best case is Cbest(n) = n-1.
This is because the count variable makes the inner loop iterate less based on the amount of iteration already done relative to the input size.

This is the most efficient bubble sort I've come across so far.